# Where do we draw the line regarding opinions of Rabbanan?

Tags: discussion, policy

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12148/).

I was the first to vote it as off-topic, as I viewed it as asking for R’ Hirsch’s personal view on Zionism. Shmuel Brin posed a fair point in the comments:

> Why are people voting this off-topic? It’s not asking his personal opinion, but his Hashkafic opinion. It’s like asking “Why did the Rambam rule like XYZ?”

This leads me to two questions:

1. Is this argument even correct? Is one’s hashkafic (not halachic) opinion considered on-topic as Judaism not Jews?
2. In the event that it is on-topic, where do we draw the line between hashkafic on-topic questions and personal off-topic questions?